# Error when using spatial reference EPSG:3440 in gdal2tiles.py

Tags: google-maps, gdal, maptiler

I was using gdal2tiles.py with spatial reference WSG84 and it was working fine. However, when I changed to spatial reference EPSG:3440. I got the the following error:

First, I run the command:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs EPSG:3440 -gcp 0 0 58.068451479718924 23.65512391903488 -gcp 21816 0 58.126966134442846 23.65512391903488 -gcp 21816 14871 58.126966134442846 23.6185834507829  myinputimage.png myoutput.vrt
```

Than, I run the command:

```
python gdal2tiles.py  myoutput.vrt
```

I got the following error:
[image]

Is there is way to fix this error or use similar spatial reference  which doesn't have this error. Notice, this error happen only when using spatial reference other than WSG84.

EDIT: I guess the issue could be that spatial reference EPSG:3440  is not inculded, but the question remain, is there away to add it to gdal reference database.

Comment: You can try to use the corresponding Proj4 string instead of the EPSG code - "+proj=utm +zone=40 +ellps=clrk80 +units=m +no_defs ". This usually does the trick for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EPSG:3440 is a projected system. The correct definition for accuracy 0.5 meter would be probably:

```
+proj=utm +zone=40 +ellps=clrk80 +towgs84=-180.624,-225.516,173.919,-0.81,-1.898,8.336,16.71006 +units=m +no_defs
```

If I have a look at http://epsg.io/3440-1439 it tells:

```
Projected bounds:
-35283.71 1840661.51
789562.66 2942956.58
```

In your command above you assign ground control points which looks like geodetic (latitude longitude numbers) such as 58.068451479718924. This is very probably wrong - as the numbers you assign are not in the projected bounds range.

You must very use in the -gcp parameter of the gdal_translate numbers which are bigger - already projected and in the above range.

It is possible to transform your lat/lon from WGS84 via the online interface at:
http://epsg.io/3440-1439/map and assign in the -gcp argument the transformed numbers.

You have marked your query with tag `maptiler` which refers to http://www.maptiler.com/. This tool would be able to assign the coordinates visually as well without a need to create VRTs - so you can click on your image and copy&paste the above coordinates in a projected system.
MapTiler generates a viewer which display the EPSG:3440 tiles in OpenLayers or transform these to a spherical mercator tiles for overlays with Google or OSM or use in mobile apps.

BTW glad to hear you use the systems gdal2tiles, maptiler and http://epsg.io/ which we have developed...